# If I develop an application in Eclipse how do I send the app to my phone?

Tags: android

Is there an easy method to send the app to my phone or do I have to do it using debugging from the development computer while being connected to the phone?

Also, do I really have to sign, version, prepare and publish the application before I can actually use it on the phone? Or, can I use it on just my phone without publishing it to the world?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I develop an application in Eclipse
>   how do I send the app to my phone?

Click the Run toolbar button, or choose Project|Run from the main menu, IIRC.

> Is there an easy method to send the
>   app to my phone or do I have to do it
>   using debugging from the development
>   computer while being connected to the
>   phone?

"using debugging from the development computer while being connected to the phone" *is* "an easy method to send the app to my phone".

> Also, do I really have to sign,
>   version, prepare and publish the
>   application before I can actually use
>   it on the phone?

All the necessary steps are handled for you by clicking Run.

> Or, can I use it on just my phone
>   without publishing it to the world?

Whether you use [Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) or [command-line tools](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html), you can push your APK into your phone without publishing it to the Android Market.

Answer (score 2):

To use it for yourself you can send it through ADB or just copy apk file to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, HTC is not connected to the computer and after developing is finished I just email APK file to myself. APK attachment is opened with HTC and installed. No need for Market publishing nor application signing ...

Answer (score 0):

Install a barcode application on your phone, then use
http://www.apkinstall.com/
-download your app on that site by browsing it
-it will give you a barcode, use your barcode app to get a link
-download from that link, istall the app after downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread, but I think this answer will help to others who are viewing this question. After you have created your files in eclipse (or any editor), navigate to the 'bin' folder of your app and you will see the .apk file there. Simply copy that over to your device via any program that you use (i personally use MobileGo). After copying the apk file, it worked on my Galaxy s2, I believe it should work like that for other devices as well.